# Fire PostBack from jqGrid cell item

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using the commerical version of jqGrid, www.trirand.net, for ASP.NET webforms.

One such grid, has a "view", "edit" and "delete" button for each row - However, these are restricted per row.

So, these cells are given a value of "True" or "False" then I'm using a custom formatter to build up a hyperlink for them using values from the `cellObject[]` object (and if false, do nothing).

However, I'd like to change these hyperlinks to page postbacks / asp.net link buttons - I appreciate jqGrid is client side so I can't add server controls inside the grid and I've read mixed review about writing your own `__doPostBack` function - And the quick experiment I've tried with this resulted in a need to call validation from the `__doPostBack`.

I do have a link button, with a command name & argument below the grid, and I can read in the `__doPostBackWithOptions` from this, however I can't figure out how I can change any values in this. Effectively, it would work equally as well, should I be able take the `link button`, change the `command name` and `command argument` and then fire the postback. Is this possible?

Another note, I've looked at the `ClientScriptManager`, but I've not been able to get it to interface with jqGrid, and it still looks like it needs to link to an existing server control?

Comment: Do you specified [custom unformatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting) (`unformat` callback) together with [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#custom_formatter)?

Comment: Hi @Oleg - No just the formatter as it's then a hyperlink directly to an "Edit" / "Delete" separate page. There's no native editing in the grid

Answer (score 0):

OK, for now I have it working in my dev environment but it feels a little "hacky"... I've basically use the custom formatter to hijack the .NET `Link Button`'s href attribute:

```
javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(
    new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl00$ctl00$ucCarePlanItem$lnkAddRecordBtn", "", true, "CarePlanSchedule", "", false, true))
```

I've then altered the second argument, the `__EVENTARGUMENT` which has fired the postback.

In the `Link Button`'s click event I've then checked for:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT")))
{ ... }
else
{ ... };
```

And finally, had to disable `EventValidation` - It's this last bit I'd like to avoid.

As the grid is loaded dynamically, to register every row as a possible event seems counter productive... And as I type, I think I may have a solution of using hidden text boxes, have the jqGrid update their values and then trigger a submit... Seems cleaner!